# Convergence of Probability Measures and the Dirac Delta

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose that we define the measures on $\mathbb{R}$:

$\displaystyle\mu_{n}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{a_{j}}+\delta_{-a_{j}})$

For $\delta$ being the Dirac delta function, and for $a_{j} \in [0,\pi]$ (I think these are probability measures).

I saw somewhere that there exists a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu_{n} \to \mu$ in the sense of weak convergence. Why would this measure $\mu$ exist? Or what would be a way to get started?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you looked at Krein-Milman and what the delta measures become in this context?

Comment: You have an issue of scaling. For example $\frac12(\delta_0+\delta_1)$ would represent the uniform distribution on $\{0,1\}$. So you need a factor of $\frac1n$ in your definition of $\mu_n$.